# ConfigError: no steps directory

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I'm facing a problem with `behave`. As I checked for some solutions there, they were supposing me to make sure my feature is in right place, but it is, and anyway it doesn't work. I get an error: `ConfigError: No steps directory .......`
I tried to execute it by using `behave` command.

My tree looks like this:
[image: n]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` file in your sub-directories (`zad1`, `features`, `steps`) for `behave` to access the file in `steps/`.

`src` probably needs it too.

Comment: Still gets the same.
`ConfigError: No steps directory in '/x/x/x/x/x/features'`

Comment: I figured it out, but I have another problem now - having inside steps/FizzBuzz.py 
`from bdd_git.zad1.src.FizzBuzz import FizzBuzz`
bdd_git is the main directory (all the files/directories from the tree in the picture are inside bdd_git)
Problem: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bdd_git'`

Comment: try `from ..src.FizzBuzz import FizzBuzz`

Comment: Also if I answered you original question, can you please accept my answer as the correct answer